# Watch Firebase data: execute action after the DOM is updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a real time chat app with Vue.js and Firebase realtime database.

When a new message is received, I want the chat window to scroll to the bottom. To achieve this, I created a watcher for the conversation data. However, the function in the watcher is executed before the DOM is updated so the scroll value isn't correct yet. Should I watch another property? How can I detect when the new data has been loaded into the DOM?

HTML Code

```
<div class="chat" ref="chat">
    <div 
      v-for="(message,key) in conversations" :key="key">
      <div class="message">
        {{message.text}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script (I'm using VueFire)

```
const conversations = db.ref('conversations');

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      conversations: {},
    }
  },
  watch: {
    conversations: function() {
      //Scroll to bottom when new message received
      this.$refs.chat.scrollTop = this.$refs.chat.scrollHeight;
    }
  }
}
```

I can fix this issue by setting a timeout but it's a dirty trick imo...

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.$refs.chat.scrollTop = this.$refs.chat.scrollHeight;
}, 300);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** DOMNodeInserted => MutationObserver

You could use a MutationObserver

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/WNvOWwp

Create a `scrollToBottom` method:

```js
...
methods: {
        scrollToBottom() {
            this.$refs.wrapper.scrollTop = this.$refs.wrapper.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
...
```

And call it whenever a new message is added:

```js
...
data() {
  return {
    mo: {}  
  }
},
mounted() {
        let vm = this;
        this.mo = new MutationObserver((mutationList, observer) => {
            vm.scrollToBottom();
        });
        this.mo.observe(this.$el, {childList: true})
    }
...
```

My variable names are a bit different than yours, but it'll work in your code once you update it.

Comment: Thank you Tanner, your solution is working but I have the following message in the console: `[Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.` I tried using MutationObserver but I have the same issue as before, should I ignore it?

Comment: Hi Julia, I've updated the answer and the Pen to use MutationObserver instead of DOMNodeInserted